# Javascript Close Modal Window When Any Link is Clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 3 hyperlinks that appear in a modal box.  When I click on one of the links, the modal box is meant to close.

example of links:

```
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="cat">Link 1</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="cat">Link 2</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="cat">Link 3</a>
```

I have successfully been able to close the modal if I specify the index of the link.

```
var links = document.getElementsByClassName("cat")[2];
```

A function is called and then displays the modal as "none":

```
links.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

Here is a [Jfiddle example...](https://jsfiddle.net/volterony/d5vw5b0z/)

This will only close the 3rd link because I am passing [2], but I would like to be able to close the modal when any of the links are clicked.

Any help appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning the `onclick` listener to 3rd link only. You can simply use a for loop to assign `onclick` listener to every links.

Change

```
var links = document.getElementsByClassName("cat")[2];
```

to

```
 var links = document.getElementsByClassName("cat");
```

And use for loop as

```
for(i=0; i<links.length;i++){
  links[i].onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d5vw5b0z/1/)

Comment: Perfecto!! Thanks a bunch Munawir :)